# how to determine the time constant from the plot

Tags: matlab, plot

In the following minimal working example,

```
M=2;
num=1/M;
den=[1 6/M];
G=tf(num,den);
step(G)
```

The output response of the system is shown

[image]

The characteristics of the system is missing the time constant which in this case Tc = M/6 (sec). Is there an option to activate this important characteristic? The time constant is the time that takes the step response to reach 63% of its final value. In this example, the plot via the steady state option, the final output is 0.167. To compute the time constant basically we compute the time of the magnitude of the output at 0.167*0.63 = 0.10521. From the plot, we can see

[image]

which matches Tc=M/6 where M=2. This is tedious workaround. Hopefully there is an option regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to plot output of `step` function to find `Tc`:

```
M=2;
num=1/M;
den=[1 6/M];
G=tf(num,den);

tvect = 0:0.0001:3;    % provide any time limits you want; 
                       % the smaller time increment the higher "accuracy"
[val, t] = step(G, tvect);
idx_Tc = find(val>=0.63*max(val), 1, 'first');

Tc = t(idx_Tc);        % Tc which you are looking for
val_Tc = val(idx_Tc);  % value at Tc
```

If you need a nice plot, you can easily create it afterwards, since you already have all required values (`t`, `val`, `Tc`, `val_Tc`).

**EDIT:**

You can extend context menu following example below:

```
M=2;
num=1/M;
den=[1 6/M];
G=tf(num,den);
step(G);

f = gcf;
c = f.CurrentAxes.UIContextMenu;
uimenu(c,'Label','Find Tc','Callback',@findTc);
f.CurrentAxes.UIContextMenu = c;
```

where function `findTc` is defined as:

```
function findTc(~,callbackdata)
    t = callbackdata.Source.Parent.Parent.CurrentAxes.Children(1).Children(2).XData;
    val = callbackdata.Source.Parent.Parent.CurrentAxes.Children(1).Children(2).YData;
    idx_Tc = find(val>=0.63*max(val),1, 'first');

    Tc = t(idx_Tc);
    val_Tc = val(idx_Tc);

    disp(['Tc: ' num2str(Tc) ' val_Tc: ' num2str(val_Tc)])
end
```

[image]

Instead of printing values in command window you can annotate the plot but I would say it's rather cosmetic change. The code above shows how you can have this feature as an option in context menu.

Comment: There are several ways to do it my question is really about having this feature as an option.

Comment: In this case you can play around with [uimenu](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uimenu.html?searchHighlight=uimenu&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) and [uicontextmenu](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontextmenu.html?searchHighlight=uimenu&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) and extend existing menu with the function you need.